How to upscale video resolution on QMEU virtual machines?
I am trying to run some KVM QEMU virtual machines. However, I am running on a machine with fairly limited resources and a 4K screen. Therefore, I would like to run the virtual machines at lower resolutions 480-1080p and then upscale the result so it isn't stupidly tiny. Is this possible and if so how can I do it?
P.S. I have tried running display scaling of 2x. However, for some reason I'm having difficulty getting it to work on some VM's and as I don't have GPU passthrough set up it will be more efficient to do the upscaling on the host machine than in the VM anyway.

So you have two steps: running a VM at an arbitrary or specific non-native resolution, and then upscaling VM resolution. Have you looked into either of these steps separately? What methods are you using to access these VMs? In my experience, the upscaling is often a feature of the client viewing the machine, while the original resolution can be set in the VM settings.

Also, you used the tag "kvm-switch", but that is a different thing than QEMU's KVM, which is a method of virtualization, I believe, and is not a "Keyboard-Video-Mouse Switch". Please select a more accurate (set of) tag(s) to help better identify your question.
